# Why is my code skipping this loop?

Tags: c++

I apologize in advance for my noob question. My first ever experience with programming has been with my current course. On to the question,

Why is my code skipping the second while loop. When I choose p or P for my input, I'm still getting asked for the inputs pertaining to the first while loop and not the second. E.g minutes instead of day minutes/night minutes.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char service;
        int number;
        int minutes;
        int dayMinutes;
        int nightMinutes;
        double bill;
        double const REG_FEE = 10.00;
        double const PREM_FEE = 25.00;
        double const REG_MIN = 0.20;
        double const PREM_DAY = 0.10;
        double const PREM_NIGHT = 0.05;

        cout << "Please enter your account number: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Please enter your service type (regular or premium): ";
        cin >> service;

        while (service == 'r' || 'R')
    {
            cout << "How many minutes have been used for this service?: ";
            cin >> minutes;

            if (minutes < 50)
            {
                bill = REG_FEE;
                cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
                cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
                cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
                cout << "You used: " << minutes << " minutes." << endl;
                cout << "Your bill is $" << bill << "." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                bill = ((minutes - 50) * REG_MIN) + REG_FEE;
                cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
                cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
                cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
                cout << "You used: " << minutes << " minutes." << endl;
                cout << "Your bill is $" << bill << "." << endl;
            }
        return 0;
    }
        while (service == 'p' || 'P')
    {
            cout << "How many minutes were used during the day?: ";
            cin >> dayMinutes;
            cout << "How many minutes were used during the night?: ";
            cin >> nightMinutes;

            if (dayMinutes > 75)
            {
                bill = ((dayMinutes - 75) * PREM_DAY) + PREM_FEE;
            }
            if (nightMinutes > 100)
            {
                bill = ((nightMinutes - 100) * PREM_NIGHT) + PREM_FEE;
                bill = bill + PREM_FEE;
                cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
                cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
                cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
                cout << "You used: " << dayMinutes + nightMinutes << " minutes." << endl;
                cout << "Your bill is $" << bill << "." << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "You have entered an invalid service code.";
            }
        return 0;
    }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You have a `return` in your loop, which makes it exit.

Comment: what is the purpose of the while loops? it looks as if you only want each loop to execute once thus the use of a loop is redundant

Comment: The while loops are broken. It should be ((service == 'r') || (service == 'R)) otherwise the condition is always true

Answer (score 2):

As @Vaughn Cato said, you have a `return 0;` in your code that is not part of a conditional statement.  I am assuming that you might need to insert the return statement into one of your if/else statements.

My best choice would be instead to use a `break;` statement instead of a `return 0;` to only exit the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is logically incorrect.
You need to change it to:

```
while (service == 'r' || service == 'R')
```

and same for the other loop:

```
while (service == 'p' || service == 'P')
```

Operator `==` has higher precedence than operator `||`.
What you have written is this:

```
while (service == 'r' || 'R')
```

So, in your case, the expression `service == 'r'` is evaluated first.
Assuming the value of `service` is `'p'`, the expression evaluates to `false`.
Next, the expression `false || 'R'` is evaluated which is always `true`, because the character `R` evaluates to `true`.
So the condition is always `true` and you always enter the first loop.
And the second loop has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first `while`'s condition is always `true` *whatever* input is.

```
while (service == 'r' || 'R')
```

is equilavent to:

`while ( (service == 'r') || 'R') )`

e.g, input `'p'`

```
while ( ('p' == 'r') || 'R') )
while ( (false || 'R') )     
while ( (false || true) )    //  'R' 's equivalent decimal is greater
                             //     than 0, so is always 'true'
while (true)
```

possible solution:

```
while ( service == 'r' || service == 'R' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every while only is executed once, it would be better to use

```
if (service == 'r' || service == 'R')
```

in stead of first while, and

```
if (service == 'p' || service == 'P')
```

in stead of second while.

The idea of while loop is to execute a block of sentences zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `while` loop as code will run only once and value of `service` is not changing inside the loop.
As earlier all have already explained to use `service == 'r' || service == 'R'`
I would like to suggest you to use `if` `elseif` instead of `while`

```
if(service == 'r' || service == 'R')
{
   // your code
}
else if(service == 'p' || service == 'P')
{
    //you code
}
```

remove `return 0;` inside these two conditions.
Use loop when you want to run a condition multiple times.

In case if you want to run it multiple time, then keep using `while` loop and just remove `return 0;` inside the loop.